# remote repository deployments

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, nexus

When I was deploying local repository files to nexus repository wso2-carbon files did not deployed on nexus repository though there wasn't any error.I want to why that happens and how can I solve that issue .

Comment: Did you check the request.log?  If there was a 200, it should be in your repository.  If not there should be a status code showing why even if no error.

Comment: thnx @joedragons I will check